# Vant Calendar: Как на функцию onConfirm форматировать данные?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Столкнулась со странной проблемой при срабатывании onConfirm. В календаре vant при изменении отмеченных дней в календаре неверно срабатывает функция.

```
onConfirm(dates) {
    (collapseRange(getPrevDates(dates)));
}
```

Следующая функция получает массив и относительно currentDate отрезает массив (оставляет те, что были раньше даты)

```
function getPrevDates(arr) {
    let newArr = arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);
    let result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
        if (newArr[i] <= currentDate) {
            result.push(newArr[i]);
        }
    }
   return result;
}
```

Следующая функция должна упорядоченный массив разделить на подмассивы, в которых даты идут по порядку разницей в один день

```
function collapseRange(arr) {
    let res = [];
    let elem = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        let date1 = new Date(arr[i].getTime());
        let date2 = new Date(arr[i - 1].getTime());
        if (date1.setDate(date1.getDate() - 1) == date2.setDate(date2.getDate())) {
            if (i == arr.length - 1) {
                elem.push(arr[i - 1]);
                elem.push(arr[i]);
                res.push(elem);
                elem = [];
            }
            elem.push(arr[i - 1]);
        } else {
            elem.push(arr[i - 1]);
            res.push(elem);
            elem = [];
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Крайняя формула вроде работает, так как если входные данные не менять и просто вызывать при нажатии onConfirm, то выводится именно то, что отмечено и в том же порядке. Но, если добавить даты или убрать отмеченные - почему-то разбивается на неправильные подмассивы. Даты остаются все равно в правильном порядке. Например:

```
(3) [Array(3), Array(2), Array(5)]
    0: 
    (3) [Mon Apr 24 2023 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время), 
         Tue Apr 25 2023 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время), 
         Wed Apr 26 2023 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время)]
    1: 
    (2) [Thu May 18 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время), 
         Fri May 19 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время)]
    2: 
    (5) [Sat May 20 2023 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время), 
         Sun May 21 2023 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время), 
         Mon May 22 2023 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время), 
         Tue May 23 2023 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время), 
         Wed May 24 2023 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время)]
```

Хотя исходя из этих данных должны быть всего два подмассива: с 24 по 26 и с 18 до 24.

Answer (score 0):

Разобралась с поставленной задачей подобным образом. Сначала также были проблемы с неверным выводом подмассивов. Однако заключалась ошибка в том, что даты у нас GMT+0300, таким образом нам нужно сравнивать не с 24 часами, а с 28 часами... Вроде работает, но может быть кто-то сможет объяснить более точно, почему так.

```
function collapseRange(arr) {
    let result = [];
    let range = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i + 1] - arr[i] <= 100800000) {
            range.push(arr[i]);
        } else {
            range.push(arr[i]);
            result.push(range);
            range = [];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```